# hibernate call stack for createQuery()

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

I am new to hibernate. I want to know exactly what happens when createQuery() is called. How hibernate internally calls the jdbc driver (based on dialect) and retrieve results, i.e. which all function calls take place or which all objects are invoked; I am interested in the entire call stack.

I have downloaded the hibernate-orm source code from github, but I am not sure where to start from. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Regards,
Souvik

Comment: Use a debugger. But a breakpoint in and look for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

to show executed sql.

In addiction you have to setup a log system (like log4j) and use this config to trace all (AST query tree, sql, jdbc parameters and so on)

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
#log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### direct messages to file hibernate.log ###
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=hibernate.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ###

log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout

#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug

### log HQL query parser activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=debug

### log just the SQL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=debug

### log schema export/update ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug

### log HQL parse trees
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug

### log cache activity ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=debug

### log transaction activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=debug

### log JDBC resource acquisition
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
```

Comment: I did try this, but I am not able to find what I was looking for in the log output. I want to know which methods(s) are called when createQuery() actually executes. May be I am not looking in the log carefully. Can you help?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in session.createQuery and debug follow log. I did in the the same to get confidence with hibernate code flow and objects. For example, dialect is used to build sql string for your query and jdbc call is done in the same way you write with plain jdbc. Follow code, there is no magic, Just a clever way to reassemble objects you use every day. I learnt a lot with a book about hibernate and debugger !

Comment: Thanks Bellabax, Boris. I took your suggestion and finally able to find the call stack for createQuery().